# How do I convert .blf data from CAN to .csv using python

Tags: python, type-conversion, can-bus

I have CAN-Data in the blf-format from the Vector software. For further investigation I want to convert it into csv format using python.

My progress so far:

```
import can
filename = "test.blf"
log = can.BLFReader(filename)
```

I dont know if thats the right way. I can't save "log" to a csv file now.

This might [help](http://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/can/io/blf.html)

Comment: If you would be content to "use python" by calling it from the command line I think you can use the `logconvert` module of python-can, e.g. `python -m can.logconvert input_file.blf output_file.csv`

Comment: I dont know about the format of the output csv-file in this case, but an exported CAN trace is not a csv, but a collection of tables (csv-files). One for each message and the signals in the message are the columns. Many libraries (like asammdf) "hide" this and for example interpolate missing values which is not necessarily what you want. I would be interested in a complete answer using `can.logconvert`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Original answer:

## List of that object does the trick

```py
import can
import csv

filename = "test.blf"
log = can.BLFReader("test.blf")
log = list(log)

log_output = []

for msg in log:
msg = str(msg)
log_output.append([msg[18:26],msg[38:40],msg[40:42],msg[46],msg[62],msg[67:90]])

with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=';', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer.writerows(log_output)
```

New answer:

Since I've posted this I actually created a library which provides a pandas like API for CAN data. Check it out [here](https://gitlab.com/lionsracing/candas). A demonstration of features can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/JulianWgs/2fa20fabfa87d709a0b6c394eba9266c).

- Common format for dealing with CAN data
- Enrich plots of the logging data with data from the dbc files automatically
- Versatile and extensible plotting functions for all kinds of signals
- Easily export CAN data to a pandas dataframe

```py
import candas as cd

db = cd.load_dbc("dbc_folder")
# Provide file without extension
log_data = cd.from_file("blf_file")
# Signals can be accessed like this
log_data["AVGcellTemperature"]
```

Comment: I tried this approach and get `assert header[0] == b"LOBJ", "Parse error"` (`File "C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Local\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\can\io\blf.py", line 129, in __iter__`). The BLF file I try to pass is a legit Vector CANoe log file. Any ideas?

Comment: Please upload the .blf somewhere and I will have a look 

Comment: I never got this error before. May be you could upload a dummy file?

Comment: It's beyond my current knowledge of CANoe to generate a dummy one (I'm new on the job), but I know for sure the file is legit because I can convert it to CSV using Vector CANoe itself (`Tools >> Logging File Conversion` dialog) with no issues.

Comment: I believe you that it is legit, but the only way to know if its a problem on your side or in the code is to give me some kind of test-blf-file. May be you can send me some log which isnt confidential. Also it just needs to be very short (1s)

Comment: @JulianWgs I have a little bit of a doubt in using your CANdas library. I'm trying to work with the library but I am running into some issues. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PrashanthL Please create an issue at the repo either at GitHub or GitLab and include a minimal example of what problem you are trying to solve. I will gladly help you :) (I know usually the repo isnt the place for questions, but for now it is Okay)