# How do I fix a corrupted .blf file (from Vector software) using python-can

Tags: python, type-conversion, can-bus

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499903/how-do-i-convert-blf-data-from-can-to-csv-using-python), except I would like to end up with a new BLF file instead of a .csv file. I am doing this to remove a corrupted object in the BLF file that keeps me from importing it into Vector's software. I imagine there is a way to directly pass the 'can.io.blf.BLFReader' class object generated by BLFReader directly to BLFWriter, but I am having trouble figuring out how. The example code below should help explain the functionality I would like to achieve:

```
import can


filename_in = "corrupted.blf"
log = can.io.BLFReader(filename_in)
filename_out = "cleaned.blf"
can.io.BLFWriter(filename_out,log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def BLFRepair(filename_in, filename_out):
""" Repairs a corrupted Vector .blf fileself.
Args:
    filename_in (str): Filename of input corrupted file.
    filename_out (str): Filename to save repaired file with.
"""
cleaned_log=BLFReader(filename_in)   # ignores errors
logger=BLFWriter(filename_out)
for msg in cleaned_log:
    logger.on_message_received(msg)

logger.stop()
```