# Converting Vector *.blf data to normal readable data for spreadsheet use with python-can or cantools

Tags: python, can-bus, canalyzer, python-can

I have a few files that were created by exporting CAN-Bus data in CANalyzer or Vector. The problem is the mainly interesting data in the file are encoded and look like this: "40c1 bf1b 490d 34b0 46c5 6ed0 a853 d856".

Is there a way to "convert" this data into normal, human readable numbers by means of the python-can or cantools?

Comment: Sounds like some proprietary format. Can't you export to csv or some other standard format instead?

Comment: Python-can is able to decode BLF, so you did already do this and got the data above as you payload? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct I already created a csv file using python can (according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499903/how-do-i-convert-blf-data-from-can-to-csv-using-python) ). However the data is still encrypted of course. Unfortunately I don't have access to the original source of the data, so I can't get any other export format.

Comment: Do you have the DBC file associated with that bus? Do you know what kind of communication is going on? Diagnostics, Flashing, normal communication?

Comment: No I don't have the dbc file but I think it's mainly diagnostics / sensor data (something like engine torque and speed maybe). It was exported with Vector CANalyzer I think. I thought maybe it was possible to 'tell' can-python that the data comes from vector as there are these interface modules predefined (https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/interfaces/vector.html) instead of needing the dbc? I mean if I imported the file back into Vector I would not need a dbc file, so the data should be decodable without it?

Comment: The Vector tools will also need information about how to decode it. In case of normal CAN, the DBC-file is needed. In case of diagnostics, the CDD or ODX files are needed. Without this, also the vector tools will not know how to decode and display the raw data. The vector modules on python-can are used for using the vector hardware as bus interface. How does the data look like in CANalyzer? Can you post a screenshot of the trace window?